# Trouble getting VBA Script to create desired chart

Tags: vba, excel

As shown in the image below, I have a chart (on the left) that I created manually.  And I have the chart on the right which I created with the following VB Script:

```
Sub StackedBarChart()
'
' StackedBarChart Macro
' 
'       
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Total").Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

End Sub
```

[image]

Where I am falling short with my macro is the following areas:

- I need to set just the "Total" data label to InsideBase
- I need to rescale the y-axis.  But, this needs to work for any data set.  So, for example, taking the highest total value and adding $2.5 to it in order to make it a decent looking chart.
- Automatically make sure that all of the Data Labels on the Legend appear.  Right now, only 4-12 appear.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With the

```
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
```

you select the whole line including the totals. So on top of your stacked chart you have the total values again, so this doubles the high.

With (and here I am not quite sure)

```
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Total").Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
```

you just supress the display of the 'Total' stack. Just try to comment this line out, and I supose that you will get another element on top.

The best you probably can do is to redo the chart manually while recording a macro and checking the statements there.

For the legend you possibly need to increase the size of the display area.

The totals you can possibly dray an invisible stack with a 100% overly in the background. Then the values should be shown but no bar is displayed.